# Rolling to a 3D cone out of a rectagular sheet of paper

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geodesic

Find cone vertex angle formed by roll-bending a rectangular sheet of paper ( $ 3 \times \sqrt 5) $ to a circular cone shape in 3D so that $P^{\prime}$ falls on P, top edge line $P^{\prime}A $ falls along $PA$ and side edge $P^{\prime} B^{\prime} $  falls on $PB$. ( Points $P,B$ are the same in space after roll). Contact of surfaces takes place on back side of paper,the bent paper cone now points up towards the number 3 shown, at some places roll rotation can be more than a turn when viewed along cone axis.

EDIT 1& 2

The conclusion is that *as long as PB falls on P'B' the **cone angle will be same.***

[image: RolledPaperCone]
[image]

Comment: You have defined $\overline{PB}$ twice. Please clarify this question by relabeling your diagram with five unique points.

Comment: Put same label  on purpose to show $ same & congruent $ points after bend/roll. Hope now it is clearer.

Comment: I cannot understand this problem : roll bending ? Five points are in a plane ?

Comment: A sheet of paper rolling may be helpful. If not clear still, please feel free to comment.

Comment: Does $P$ lie inside the rectangle or $\overline{PP'}$ is a side of the rectangle? That is, are $\overline{PA}$ and $\overline{PB}$ edges of the paper or just drawn lines on paper?

Comment: $ \overline {PA}, \overline   {PB }$ are not edges of paper. They are just pencil lines on paper drawn just to indicate target direction ,just to indicate where the edge goes and how inclined it is.after rolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the situation correctly, the cone is folded thus:

[image: Folding]
<sub>(source: [nominal-animal.net](http://www.nominal-animal.net/answers/cone-folding.png))</sub>

and the shaded area below is what actually is folded into a truncated cone:

[image: Cones]
<sub>(source: [nominal-animal.net](http://www.nominal-animal.net/answers/cones.png))</sub>

If we extend the lines $\overline{BP}$ and $\overline{B'P'}$, they eventually intersect, with angle $\alpha$. The original diagram gives us that angle, because we have a right triangle ($(\sqrt{5})^2=5=1^2+2^2$), and left side of the sheet is parallel to $\overline{B'P'}$:
$$\sin{\alpha} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\tag{1}\label{1}$$

Whenever we fold a circular sector of paper (sector angle $\alpha$, radius $s$) into a right circular cone, the length of the perimeter is $p = 2 \pi s \alpha / 360°$. For the resulting right circular cone, the radius is $r = p / (2 \pi) = s \alpha / 360°$.

If we look at a cross section of the right circular cone, we see the axis, radius $r$, and side $s$ form a right triangle, with the angle $\theta$ at the apex being half the cone vertex angle $\phi$, $\phi = 2 \theta$:
$$\sin(\theta) = r/s = \frac{\alpha}{360°}$$
and therefore
$$\phi = 2 \arcsin \left ( \frac{ \alpha }{ 360° } \right )\tag{2}\label{2}$$

Note that equation $\eqref{2}$ applies in general, not just in this special case. Might be useful when making party hats.

If we plug in $\eqref{1}$ into $\eqref{2}$, we get
$$\phi = 2 \arcsin \left ( \frac{ \arcsin \left ( \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \right ) }{ 360° } \right ) \approx 8.5°$$

Comment: $ \pi \sin \frac{\phi}{2} = \frac{\alpha}{2}; \, $ Was n't that simple ?   One comment: The right angled $ (1,2,\sqrt 5) $ triangle gets covered twice. The rest of the rolled " rectangular "surface is a truncated cone but not symmetrically truncated.

Comment: @Narasimham: Right; you could put glue on to the triangle part, then pull the right side onto it from "behind" the screen. (I had to make a paper version to visualize this..) For a symmetrically truncated cone the top and bottom edges are elliptical curves (a bit like I sketched in the image). Note that you still get the same cone if you just put $\overline{P'B'}$ over $\overline{PB}$ *anywhere* (well almost: not past sector center), $P$ and $P'$ do not need to overlap: the paper then just covers a different part of the cone.  Only the sector angle matters!

Comment: You got it all perfectly right. Once I uploaded a video also but.. Can I ask if you have the time ,can you upload here or on YouTube a small demo ? I had eaten peanuts on the beach in such rolled paper cones for years, knew such a simple relation exists, but did not correlate in a fully circumstantial way.. all because the text book does not give it in that inconvenient way.

Comment: @Narasimham: I'm too camera-shy, but I added a three-step folding guide to my answer; perhaps that helps a bit? For the circular sector, just leave a small tab on one side for gluing. (If you haven't done so, I recommend gluing up the Platonic solids from paper; it's fun and really helps with visualizing the 3D stuff.)

Comment: Fine,basically ok.  Platonic solids? I  once folded up the icosi-dodecahedron.

Comment: @Narasimham: Showoff! :) Actually, I find the variations in the tiling, and their symmetries and connectivity more interesting than the final shape itself. As an example, consider the [ETOPO2 Icosahedron](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/relief/ETOPO2/etopo2icosahedron.pdf) [pdf] map; there might be a better (not aligned to latitude/longitude) tiling with discontinuities at sea or deserts, with much less distortions than current maps. My favourite is using a pre-oriented icosahedron and 3D subdivision, to describe a 3D direction using a single integer at arbitrary precision.

Comment: ok, but  such .. follow  penguin on your site?

Comment: It's [Tux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tux). I use Linux, as I can mold it to fit my workflow, and not the other way around as proprietary OSes do.